# Attaching Screenshot to Rally Testcase Result

Tags: java, rest, rally

I am using Rally API/Java. I need to attach a screenshot in Rally Testcase when i create it. I am doing it but i am getting an error in my attachment response.

The Response message is get and the error is:

{"CreateResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": ["**We're sorry!  An unexpected error has occurred.**
We have recorded this error and will begin to investigate it.  In the meantime, if you would like to speak with our Support Team, please reference the information below:
java.lang.NullPointerException
02/25/2015 05:07:01 PM Asia/Karachi"], "Warnings": ["It is no longer necessary to append \".js\" to WSAPI resources."]}}

I get no message it my request and it creates the request succcessfully.

Need help with this!

My attachement code is as follows:

```
// File handle for image to attach
        RandomAccessFile myImageFileHandle;
        String imageFilePath = "c:/Screenshots/";
        String imageFileName = "AWSCEUbuntuServerSmall.jpg";
        String fullImageFile = imageFilePath + imageFileName;
        String imageBase64String;
        long attachmentSize;

        // Open file
        myImageFileHandle = new RandomAccessFile(fullImageFile, "r");

//Add Attachment

                        // Get and check length
                        long longLength = myImageFileHandle.length();
                        long maxLength = 5000000;
                        if (longLength >= maxLength) throw new IOException("File size >= 5 MB Upper limit for Rally.");
                        int fileLength = (int) longLength;            

                        // Read file and return data
                        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fileLength];
                        myImageFileHandle.readFully(fileBytes);
                        imageBase64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(fileBytes);
                        attachmentSize = fileLength;

                        // First create AttachmentContent from image string
                        JsonObject myAttachmentContent = new JsonObject();
                        myAttachmentContent.addProperty("Content", imageBase64String);
                        CreateRequest attachmentContentCreateRequest = new CreateRequest("AttachmentContent", myAttachmentContent);
                        CreateResponse attachmentContentResponse = restApi.create(attachmentContentCreateRequest);
                        String myAttachmentContentRef = Ref.getRelativeRef(attachmentContentResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                        System.out.println("Attachment Content created: " + myAttachmentContentRef);            

                        // Now create the Attachment itself
                        JsonObject myAttachment = new JsonObject();
                        myAttachment.addProperty("Workspace", workspaceRef);
                        myAttachment.addProperty("TestCaseResult",ref);
                        myAttachment.addProperty("Content", myAttachmentContentRef);
                        myAttachment.addProperty("Name", "AttachmentFromREST.jpg");
                        myAttachment.addProperty("Description", "Attachment From REST");
                        myAttachment.addProperty("ContentType","image/jpg");
                        //myAttachment.addProperty("Size", attachmentSize);
                        myAttachment.addProperty("User", userRef);


                        CreateRequest attachmentCreateRequest = new CreateRequest("Attachment", myAttachment);
                        CreateResponse attachmentResponse = restApi.create(attachmentCreateRequest);
                        String myAttachmentRef = Ref.getRelativeRef(attachmentResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                        System.out.println("Attachment  created: " + myAttachmentRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

I submitted this defect yesterday: NullPointerException when posting attachments to a user's non-default workspace.

Comment: I did too. And i got the email from Rally regarding this aswell. Thanks. Looking forward for the fix.